# Backend admin panels not shown

Tags: typo3

somehow I messed up my typo3 installation (legacy installation with bootstrap package).

During an upgrade 11.5.33 to 11.5.36 suddenly the installation page showed up, as during the initial installation. I managed to restore everything by editing the LocalConfiguration.php.

The website is back online. But all the admin panels (maintenance, settings, upgrade, etc). just show a blank page:

[image]

If I try to edit user settings or if I try to generate new content on the website the following error appears:

> "503 Oops, an error occurred! Unable to generate a URL for the named route "wizard_element_browser" because this route was not found."

Also it is not possible to log on as user "admin", but my account has admin rights.

In the protocol there is an error:

> Core: Error handler (BE): PHP Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/typo3/sysext/viewpage/Resources/Public/Css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/clients/client26/web45/web:/var/www/clients/client26/web45/private:/var/www/clients/client26/web45/tmp:/var/www/stmartin-kelsterbach.de/web:/srv/www/stmartin-kelsterbach.de/web:/usr/share/php5:/usr/share/php:/tmp:/usr/share/phpmyadmin:/etc/phpmyadmin:/var/lib/phpmyadmin:/dev/random:/dev/urandom) in /var/www/clients/client26/web45/web/typo3_src-11.5.36/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php line 2317

I tried to open the install tool, but when I call the install.php also a complete blank page is shown.
I cleared all caches (frontend, backend and browser) and deleted all cookies in the browser.
I also reinstalled the bootstrap package manually, but this also did not help.

Unfortunately I have no backup and have no clue, how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds very likely be a known issue with open_basedir:

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/101921

Could it be that your webservice provider also recently enabled that setting, or you during the upgrade?

I'm afraid you'd have to use mentioned patches to resolve that. Or see if you could disable your open_basedir settings.

Your problem likely happened if typo3conf/LocalConfiguration "somehow" went away during the update and the backend thought you might be using a fresh installation. In rare cases, the PHP opcode cache could interfer too, when you change symlinks from the core. Entering the install tool directly and clearing caches should help in that case. But hard to say in hindsight.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am pretty sure, that I deleted the LocalConfiguration. 
I just checked the changes of the patch and it looks like it is already applied in my installation (11.5.36).
Unfortunately when I try to use the install tool, only a blank page is shown in my browser. Any suggestions, how to. get the install tool to work?
Thank you!